# How to install Unity3D on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, unity3d

Is there any way to install Unity 3D without wine? Installation from terminal would be good.

Comment: Did you try [following their instructions](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2#post-3662605)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last .deb version was actually Unity 2017.2.1f1. After that all the other version came in as .sha extension. .deb version actually automatically installs all the required dependencies. But now you have to install the dependencies on your own first.

Install the dependencies

```
sudo apt install gconf-service lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libasound2 libc6 libc6-i386\
libcairo2 libcap2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgcc1\
libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgl1-mesa-glx libglib2.0-0 libglu1-mesa libgtk2.0-0\
libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1\
libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxtst6 zlib1g debconf npm
```

I also recommend installing build essentials

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

After that go to this link [Unity on Linux: Release Notes and Known Issues - Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2)

Click on .html download links of the Unity version you want and select Linux download assistant.

After it is installed you can simply double click the setup file or run that using command line by:

```
cd Downloads
./UnitySetup*
```

Answer (score 44):

The recommended way of installing Unity on Linux is by first installing Unity Hub.

Unity Hub setup file:

https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/hub/prod/UnityHub.AppImage

Make sure that UnityHub.AppImage file is executable.

```
$ chmod +x path/to/UnityHub.AppImage
```

You can install the preferred version of Unity in the Installs section of Unity Hub application. It will automatically download and install it for you.

[image: Install Unity on Ubuntu Linux]

I wrote an article describing each step in detail, which you can find from the link below:

https://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-unity-linux/

Comment: This answer worked for me when accepted answer didn't.  I should note however that I had to manually make the UnityHub.AppImage file executable after downloading. +1

Comment: This shouldn't be jumping through hoops.

Answer (score 40):

Unity3D is being released via a "Download Helper" now. Instructions to use it are as follows:

1. Head to the [Unity-on-Linux Release Thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/) and go to the last page. The last post will contain the latest release. As of the time of this posting, that's [this one](https://beta.unity3d.com/download/dad990bf2728/public_download.html). Download it.
2. Make that download executable. For example, `chmod +x UnitySetup-2018.2.7f1`
3. Install the prerequisites via

   ```
   sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0 libsoup2.4-1 libarchive13 libpng16-16 libgconf-2-4 lib32stdc++6 libcanberra-gtk-module
   ```
4. Run the installer.

   ```
   ~/Downloads/UnitySetup-2018.2.7f1
   ```
5. I like to place it in the `/opt` folder once it's installed and create a link so that I can launch it from the command line.

   ```
   cd
   sudo mv Unity-2018.2.7f1 /opt/Unity3D
   sudo ln -s /opt/Unity3D/Editor/Unity /usr/bin/unity3d
   ```

Once that's done, you can type `unity3d` to launch the Unity3D Editor.

Comment: But its not recommended as unity dropped debian packages afterwards and all unity 2018 versions need to be installed in the above way,  Unity Hub is also not available on the deb package.

Comment: The deb file of the Unity 3D Linux Editor Installer from [here](http://beta.unity3d.com/download/ad31c9083c46/public_download.html) doesn't work in 18.04. It is an older release that was released in 2017.

Comment: Looks like it's working. Good idea to move it to /opt rather than install it directly. It's a good way to avoid installing as root.

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
i get this error when i try to run Unity

Comment: According it's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/InstallingUnityLinux.html), now, [UnitySetup-2019.1.0f2](http://beta.unity3d.com/download/292b93d75a2c/UnitySetup-2019.1.0f2?_ga=2.156538491.1596126683.1581966887-1699175511.1581966887) is the newest available!