# Unity3d crash on open on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, unity, gtk, crash

I have a problem that bugged me for quite some time now
I'm trying to Install Ubity3d on Ubuntu
I Followed some instructions that i've found after some research
I downloaded and installed UnityHub and the latest release (UnitySetup-2019.1.0f2) that i found on [Unity on Linux: Release Notes and Known Issues](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2)

and i moved the installed unity file from **Home** to **opt** folder and made it run on command *unity3d* and here is what i did exactly

```
sudo mv Unity-2019.1.0f2 /opt/Unity3D
sudo ln -s /opt/Unity3D/Editor/Unity /usr/bin/unity3d
```

and the problem is that every time i open Unity editor (via both the command line and UnityHub) the unity Launcher appears for moments to proccess and then crashes and the editor doesn't open and the error changes everytime i try to open the program here are 2 forms of errors that appeared to me, here is the first

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[Unity Package Manager (Upm)]
Parent process [5258] was terminated
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and the second
    Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
    Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

```
(unity-editor:6651): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_file_chooser_widget_set_current_name: assertion 'priv->action == 
GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE || priv->action == 
GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_CREATE_FOLDER' failed
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[Unity Package Manager (Upm)]
Parent process [6651] was terminated
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

the third is

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[0616/110743:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(161)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See     
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[0616/110744:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(207)] Gtk: 
gtk_window_present_with_time: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
USER@USER:~$ [Unity Package Manager (Upm)]
Parent process [7583] was terminated
```

and stuck on that....
well i know that there's something wrong with GTK but i have no experiace with it and i didn't find anything useful on this matter on google

> OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTC

Comment: Same problem here. Older versons work, but not the newer ones. I'm wondering whether it's a missing dependency or an actual bug.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue, and my problem is that I haven't install Gtk in ubuntu, you can try this:
`sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`

Comment: This did not get rid of the warnings about no transient parent for me on ubuntu 18.04. And I'm confused about the difference between your answer and what [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1078159/606260) suggests - is that just due to the fact that that answer is older?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem, but I found something werid.

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 18.04.3 LTS with Unity 2017.2.0b11 and I'm having problems of Unity crashing when opening a project.

But, if I open a project when Unity Hub is open, then it crashes less (it keeps on happening, but eventually it will start up).

Even that I don't use Unity Hub, all the projects I have are stored in the Unity Editor; seems that having Unity Hub open helps Unity to crash less.

I don't know what happends, but at least, it works for me.