# How to install Unity3D using Unity Hub

Tags: software-installation, unity3d

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1078159/307184) and it does not work.

1. the devs have stopped posting builds [there](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2). they used to post bimonthly, the last post and build dates back to a year. it is critically out of date.
2. it is not the prefered and recomended install method for linux/ubuntu by the unity devs. they prefer we use the unity hub.

I also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109342/307184) 
([YouTube video](https://youtu.be/vBs7csdlsgI) by the same guy since the stackoverflow and source he links names match and since the ubuntu desktop cusomisations are exactly the same in the youtube video and the gif). This guy has got the right idea!! if a developer makes a native solution for you, you try that first.

But as you can see in his stackoverflow answer and video: things have changed even more still since the release of that launcher.

The launcher is no longer missing any dependencies pre-launch, it runs out-of-the-box on a vanilla ubuntu 19.10 with nothing else changed. That's one difference. Also it looks and behaves nothing alike visually. It's a v2 and it does have it's own quirks.

What is the method **today**?

I try to use the "Unity Hub" which is the recommended (and only?) method to install Unity on ubuntu.

I first have to add a license, then I have to set the download folder (which is ignored since it downloads to /tmp anyways)

Then I have to select and download a unity version :

[image: choose a unity version to download]

[image: downloading unity]

Once the download finishes it looks like this:

[image: no result]

if I, at this point, choose the project tab and hit "new" it still rejects me :

[image: no editor installed, please install unity before creating a project]

If I try to open the folder I find in `/tmp`; "unityhub-9fbe5a20-6305-11ea-bdba-858cc54fd2fc"
with what seems like the right set of files : "Unity.tar.xz", "UnitySetup-Linux-IL2CPP-Support-for-Editor-2020.1.0a25.tar.xz", ect... then it just adds a new item named after the grandparent of that item (if I select "/tmp/unityhub-9fbe5a20-6305-11ea-bdba-858cc54fd2fc/Unity.tar.xz" it will be called "tmp", and I can no longer add another item from the entire /tmp tree because itt considers that it is the "same item". if I rename the folder and move it to "~/Documents" and open "~/Documents/unityEngine/Unity.tar.xz", the item in the list will be called "Documents") :

[image: locate result]

If I then try creating a new project, the window opens up but :

[image: create new project]

... upon clicking "create" I get a contentless error message box and from there on out the app bugs out and becomes more or less unresponsive and must be closed by force  :

[image: error box and crash]
[image: the three error windows]

Comment: Nope that answer and those packages date back to September 2018. Unity hub (which is what I'm trying to use) hadn't even started development back then. The method of installing as per official unity3d recommendations has been completely flipped on its head since then. https://store.unity.com/download

Comment: you didn't read my post AGAIN. I also included that answer and my question is actually also a step by step describing why that specific solution broke down recently.

Comment: This have happened to me several times before (download gone after it finished). In my case it seems to be caused by corrupted download. I solve it by redownloading several times. Hope it helps

Comment: is there no other place I can download it? this is arcane technology. corrupted non-resumable downloads shouldn't be happening in 2020

Comment: To be sure, you can look at `~/.config/UnityHub/logs/info-log.json` and see the error yourself. If you are adventurous, the logs will show you the url of the download (mine shows `Something went wrong while downloading <url> Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT`) and you can try to download it manually. After that you can manually extract and use the locate button on the hub

Comment: I was hoping unity would provide a linux torrent to get unity. they do this for windows and mac : https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive just not linux

Comment: @jrandiny you were right. it sucks to say but brute forcing it seems to be the only way. after my eighth download, at a time of day where my internet was faster, it finally worked. I'd really liked it if unity made a change to the unity hub to make downloads crash/error protected and resumable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that Unity Hub download are non-resumeable, so any problem with the network will cause the download to fail (usually without any message).

Sadly the easiest solution is to retry the download until it succeeds.

There are alternative method by manually downloading and extracting the component required but keep in mind that is is not officially supported. You can follow the following steps if you want to try downloading it manually

- Find the url of Unity download by using one of the following ways

  - Check Unity Hub log at `~/.config/UnityHub/logs/info-log.json`
  - Open `https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/hub/prod/releases-linux.json`
- Download the package manually
- Extract it to a known location
- Use the "Locate" button on Unity Hub and give the path of the extracted package

Answer (score 0):

I found a guide that might help you:
https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/InstallingUnityLinux.html

Just to summarize, you must install the setup utility, then change the permission to "make executable and run" then follow the instructions.
If the above fails, try installing the missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4
```

Comment: see : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216224/how-to-install-unity3d-as-of-10-03-2020#comment2049403_1216224 that guide references and old build of unity. I wanted to try the 2020 one. good find regardless.

Comment: sorry. i thought its 2020.1 because in the url its docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/...